# How to cross compile wxwidgets application for windows under linux

Tags: wxwidgets

I have already installed the cross compilers "x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++" and "i686-w64-mingw32-g++" to build 32 bit and 64 bit applications and I have downloaded the source code of the wxwidgets 3.0.3.

1. How do I build the source to be usable for the cross compiler?
2. Which commands do I have to send to the compiler to build a wxwidgets application?

Comment: There are more than many answers you can find, if you google. https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Getting_Started_with_wxWidgets

Answer (score 1):

> > How have I to built the source to be usable for the cross compiler?

I'd suggest using prebuilt binaries, rather than trying to cross compile the
wxWidgets library with MinGW. Compiling your own application to cross is
difficult enough without the headache of trying to use the same process
to make the Windows version of the libraries you need with the build system
the developers provided.

When you use MinGW in linux, you'll need accessible all headers, libraries, 
and DLLs (if you don't static compile) for the project you are compiling for a 
Windows target. The linux version of these won't work.

> > And which commands have I to send to the compiler to build a wxwidgets application?

It's no different than building for a linux platform, save you'll need 
accommodation for all the Windows versions of what I stated above. Which
commands you'll send to the compiler to build the application will be 
subjective to your project, however you'll need to include the headers in your
build, and you'll need to link the Windows libraries in your linking,
as well as if you don't static compile all of this, you'll need the
wxWidgets DLL to run the application.

I've been cross building applications using this method for quite a while.
It works great, but being that it's a complex process and I'm honestly not all
that great at it, I tend to use as many pre-built, and/or header-only libraries
as I can, as it cuts down on the complication of cross building the application.

And while I encourage you to learn how to do this yourself, I only encourage
it if learning how to do this is your end goal. If you just need an to build
an application, I'd sooner encourage a MinGW setup in native Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can cross-compile wxWidgets as any other project using autoconf:

```
$ mkdir build-msw
$ cd build-msw
$ ../configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --with-msw ...any other configure options...
$ make
```

(of course, use `--host=i686-w64-mingw32` if you want to use the 32 bit compiler).

Building the application depends on the make/build tool you're using but globally it's not any different from doing it for native application (which is described in the documentation), you just need to use the correct compiler and correct `wx-config` (i.e. the one generated by the build above).

Comment: Ok I have compiled wxwidgets successfully. I can compile my program but the linker gives an error                                                                              /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lwx_mswu_xrc-3.0 and so on.  How can I solve this?

Comment: Do you use `wx-config --libs`?

Comment: Sure. But now I have the wxwidgets for linux and the other for cross compiling for windows. Is this a problem for wx-config?

Comment: The simplest thing to do is to just use the `build-msw/wx-config` (with full path, of course). Otherwise, after doing `make install`, you can also pass `--host=...-mingw32` option to the installed `wx-config` to make it select the right one.